# English short grammar books recommedation

Tags: grammar

I hope this message finds you all well.

I want to study English grammar, but I could not find good resources for me, I want to study shorter books before the longer ones, but I could not find any short ones.
Why it seems in English there are only too long and comprehensive books for grammar, and there are no short ones? I want to study short books first, and then proceed to long ones. I suppose this method would be better and easier for leaning.

Comment: Do you want a pedgaogic grammar (a grammar book for English learners) or a descriptive grammar (a grammar book that describes how English 'works' but does not attempt to teach correct usage)?

Comment: Well, I could not really understand what a descriptive grammar really means, the reason I am asking the question is to find some books to study English grammar, and to do this gradually, beginning with the short books and then advance to longer ones.
I think it would be better if you can give me examples of both types of books if you could.
Thanks

Comment: Then I recommend _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_ as a descriptive grammar. It's about 300 pages. A grammar for English learners that I recommend is _Practical English Usage_ by Swan. It is organised alphabetically by grammar topic. Once you are through with those two, come back here and ask for longer and more advanced works.

Comment: First, thank you a lot for considering my question.
Second, this is the first time I have heard about descriptive grammar, certainly I will try these books.
Third, I do not intend to study more advanced grammar, actually I have the three books by Azar which seems the same as Swan's, and I think it is a gigantic one, thus I wanted shorter one.
Lastly, I have found what I wanted (there has been long time since I have posted the question) in the form of the grammar banks in some general courses for teaching English.
Again thank you a lot, you opened new perspectives to me.

Comment: You can read an explanation of descriptive grammar here: https://www.languagehumanities.org/what-is-descriptive-grammar.htm

Comment: You can read an explanation of pedagogical grammar here: https://www.languagehumanities.org/what-is-a-pedagogical-grammar.htm

Comment: If Swan is too long and not organised according to your needs, then I recommend one of the Murphy series. For example: https://www.amazon.co.uk/English-Grammar-Use-Book-Answers/dp/1108457657/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1KQZUMLBRX2L1&keywords=murphy+grammar&qid=1700554498&sprefix=murphy+grammar%2Caps%2C78&sr=8-1 Best wishes with learning English!